# How do I change the jQuery Datepicker hover border and font color over the "present/today's"date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I can't seem to find help anywhere on the web for this specialized CSS code, but my goal/ultimate intention is to have the current day behave like the rest of the selectable dates. (same behaviour as the hover effect) applied to the current date as well. I am not sure where to adjust it in the CSS. I am not sure if its possible?

Here's a pic of my desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* current input value background color */
.ui-datepicker-current-day
{
    background: #0B3F71;
}
/* today's background color */
.ui-datepicker-today 
{
    background: none;
}
.ui-datepicker-today:hover {
    background: #999999;
}
.ui-datepicker-today a:hover { 
    color: #212121; 
}
```